# How to rename a movie file by using its internal name attribute?

Tags: video, 14.10, files, batch-rename

I had to recover a bunch of movie files from my external HDD due to filesystem corruption and used `photorec` to do so. Now all my files have random names like `f00000.avi`. We are talking about 1000+ movies here, so renaming them manually would be pretty tedious. As  I understand, most movie files have their titles stored inside the header as well, so is there a way to quickly rename a bunch of files by replacing the random names by the title of the movie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with mediainfo:

```
mediainfo f00000.avi
```

To rename all .avi files in the current directory, run:

```
for f in *.avi;do title=$(mediainfo $f|grep -i "movie name"|cut -d":" -f2);mv -v "$f" "$title";done
```

Install mediainfo using the command: `sudo apt-get install mediainfo`

Comment: In the off chance the file doesnt have a title in mediainfo what would happen if I run that script. Would it get an empty name?

Comment: No, you will get this error message "No such file or directory".